# Running two Python 2.7 scripts simultaneously

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two Python scripts, one of which is `try.py` which contains this:

```
import os

os.system('python hello.py')

print "over"
```

This script calls another script by name `hello.py`, and `hello.py` contains:

```
import time

var = 1

while (var < 60):
    var = var + 1
    print var
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

There are two problems which I am facing:

- One is I want to run both the scripts simultaneously.

  but in my case my `try.py` script continues to run after `hello.py` is finished running.

Comment: what is "python shell" what is "cmd"? Why do you need to run hello and try "simultaneously". Do you need try to block why hello is running? Are you trying to do some kind of multi-processing or multi-threading?

Comment: @Bi Rico yes i need some kind of multi processing and multi threading

Comment: Your programs run correctly for the code you have written. When `try` is run it calls `hello` and after `hello.py` completes the `over` statement is printed.

Comment: but i want both of them to run simulataneously

Comment: You haven't defined what "simultaneously" means for your case. To answer your question we really need to know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Exactly, run what concurrently? You are calling a module from another.

Comment: after hello.py script is called and is executing, i want to continue executing the try.py ... before hello.py is completed

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'hello.py'])

print "over"
p.wait()
```

Comment: Thank u very much sir